# Find the unique item in front of the duplicated rows and insert in the empty column R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

As part of my code, I created a DataFrame as follows,I want to completely remove the rows if all the columns are equal (I know how to implement this part )and Find the unique item in front of the duplicated rows and insert in the empty column (it can be second column or third or forth)

```
   User Name        part1             part2              part3
 1 WolfelFigaro    "bonglez"        "bonglez"          "bonglez"   
 2 WolfelFigaro    "bonglez"        "bonglez"          "bonglez"   
 3 DeEvolver247    "bonglez"         ""                ""   
 4 DeEvolver247    "bonglez"         "xx"              ""   
 5 Raymond46194270 "x"               ""                ""   
 6 Raymond46194270 "bonglez"         ""                ""   
 7 merapimanf      "9NewsQueensland" ""                ""
```

The out put that I want:

```
   User Name        part1             part2              part3

 1 WolfelFigaro     "bonglez"           
 2 DeEvolver247     "bonglez"         "xx"              ""   
 3 Raymond46194270  "x"               "bonglez"         ""   
 4 merapimanf       "9NewsQueensland" ""                ""
```

Comment: Why is `"bonglez"` moved to `part2` for `Raymond46194270`, but `"bonglez"` *not* moved to `part3` for `DeEvolver247`?

Comment: becuse we have one "bonglez" , I dont want repetitive..

Comment: But user `WolfelFigaro` has three `"bonglez"`, why not reduce that to only one?

Comment: Yes you are right I made a mistake

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df%>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("part")) %>%
  na.omit()%>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(`User Name`)%>%
  mutate(name = str_c("part", row_number()))%>%
  pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   User Name [4]
  `User Name`     part1           part2   part3  
  <chr>           <chr>           <chr>   <chr>  
1 WolfelFigaro    bonglez         bonglez bonglez
2 DeEvolver247    bonglez         xx      NA     
3 Raymond46194270 x               bonglez NA     
4 merapimanf      9NewsQueensland NA      NA
```

EDIT:
Since the question was edited. The correct answer is given by [@ Ian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67493407/find-the-unique-item-in-front-of-the-duplicated-rows-and-insert-in-the-empty-col/67493586?noredirect=1#comment119296861_67493586)

```
data %>% 
    pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
    group_by(`User Name`) %>% 
    summarise(value = unique(value[value != ""])) %>% 
    mutate(names = paste0("part",row_number()))  %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "names", values_from = "value", values_fill = "")
```

Comment: Why I get this error : Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: @user14269252 did you use `n()` anywhere in your code? Because I did not

Comment: Can I see how you generated the DataFrame for the data that I put?

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me solve this error : Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `name`.
ℹ `name = str_c("part", row_number())`.
x could not find function "str_c"
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: "User Name" = "User Name".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I think this approach is very close to what the OP is looking for, but maybe something more like ```data %>% pivot_longer(-1) %>% group_by(`User Name`) %>% summarise(value = unique(value[value != ""])) %>% mutate(names = paste0("part",row_number()))  %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "names", values_from = "value", values_fill = "")```

Comment: @user14269252 `str_c` is from `library(stringr)`, you can get all the needed packages with `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: I added library(stringr)
require(stringr).the error has solved but the result is A tibble: 4 x 10

Comment: @IanCampbell that does not give the expected results. look at the results i have and the one OP posted

Comment: Yes your answer provides me correct table lan

Comment: The real innovation here is creating the column names with `row_number()`, all the credit to Onyambu.

Comment: Onyambu your answer gives me 4*10 table, lan answer gives me the correct maybe you can edit the answer